# How to get order list for logged in customer in magento

Tags: magento

I am working on getting list of order numbers(name) ordered by a customer. I have tried using

`Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);`

but didn't works for me? Actually i am working on help desk module and trying to assign orders to the tickets.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok friends thanks for your hints, I got this by using this

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
      Mage::app();       

      $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId())
        ->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
        ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
    ;   

     $this->setOrders($orders); 

     foreach ($orders as $order):

    echo $order->getRealOrderId().'&nbsp;at&nbsp;'.$this->formatDate($order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()).'&nbsp;('.$order->formatPrice($order->getGrandTotal()).')';

    endforeach;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try this:

```
$yourCustomerId = '123123';
$field          = 'customer_id';
$collection     = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
                   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                   ->addFieldToFilter($field, $yourCustomerId);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($collection);
echo "</pre>";
```

---

```
// if the customer is logged in you can add this
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
    $yourCustomerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
    $field          = 'customer_id';
    $collection     = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                       ->addFieldToFilter($field, $yourCustomerId);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($collection);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this as well,

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$email = $customer->getEmail();
```

Now you have customer email address in your $email variable. So you can easily get order collection using this email address as following:

```
 $orderCollection = Mage::getModel(‘sales/order’)->getCollection();
 $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter(‘customer_email’, $email);

foreach ($orderCollection as $_order)
{
    echo $_order->getRealOrderId() ;
    echo $this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()) ;
    echo $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $this->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) ;
    echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal());
    echo $_order->getStatusLabel();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

$orders->getSelect()->where('e.customer_id ='.$customer_id);