# How do I get the shipping address and order status in Magento?

Tags: magento

I have this code:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');

foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
    echo $item->getName();
    echo $item->getId();
    echo Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($item->getPrice());
}
```

But I want to get shipping address and order status of each item I ordered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get all orders for the current log in customer

```
$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();

$_orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
                   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                   ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);
                   /* to get last order only -- uncomment
                   ->setOrder('created_at', Varien_Data_Collection_Db::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
                   ->setPageSize(1);
                   */


foreach($_orders as $order) {
    foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
        echo $item->getName();
        echo $item->getId();
        echo Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($item->getPrice());
    }

  //display status
  echo $order->getStatusLabel();
  //display shipping address
  print_r($order->getShippingAddress()->getData());
}
```

To get order info for a particular order by order_id then

```
$order_id = 123; // put your order id here
$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);

if(!$_order->getID()){
    echo 'Order not found.';
}
else{

   //display shipping address
   print_r($_order->getShippingAddress()->getData());

   foreach($_order->getAllItems() as $order) {
     echo $order->getName();
     echo $order->getId();
     echo Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($order->getPrice());
     echo $order->getStatusLabel();

   }
}
```

This code get the customer cart (so this is before you place an order)

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
```

Comment: Hmm someone downvoted your answer and didn't mention why..
Ah well,

I tried your code but i get this fatal error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in C:\Development\fabriqmagento\app\design\frontend\default\fabriq\template\customer\account\dashboard.phtml

Comment: Try the entire code again (I make some update). Also did you input a valid $order_id

Comment: If you are on the account dashboard then you would have to get the order_id by using the customer_id ... take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161664/how-to-get-order-list-for-logged-in-customer-in-magento

Answer (score 1):

Get shipping details by order id

```
$order_id = 2314; //use your own order id

$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id); //load order by order id

$shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();

echo $shipping_address->getTelephone();

echo $shipping_address->getPostcode(); //use print_r($shipping_address->getData()); to get all the available elements of the object
```